# SELECT multiple values from a single column in Wordpress Database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select

I am trying to output the post details, as well as some custom fields in wordpress's database.
I have custom fields called 'thumbnail' and 'video'

```
SELECT ID, post_title, post_content, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id=wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = "thumnail"
OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = "video"
```

So far I am getting individual rows like this:

```
| ID  | Title     | Content     | Custom Fields                      |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 234 | INCEPTION | Content etc | wp-content/thumbnail/inception.jpg |
| 234 | INCEPTION | Content etc | wp-content/video/inception.flv     |
```

but what i would like is (ie one line per post)

```
|ID |Title     |Content     |Thumbnail                  |Video                      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|234|INCEPTION |Content etc |wp-content/..inception.jpg |wp-content/..inception.flv |
```

Could someone advise on how to separate the different values into columns within the SELECT statement?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This process is called "pivot table" or "crosstab report". There is no PIVOT command in MySQL but it can be done manually, here are two examples. The first example uses [IF statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html), the second one [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html). And an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) is used to get rid of the duplicate rows.

```
SELECT ID, post_title, post_content,
MAX( IF ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = "thumnail", wp_postmeta.meta_value, '' ) ) AS Thumbnail,
MAX( IF ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = "video", wp_postmeta.meta_value, '' ) ) AS Video
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id=wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ( "thumnail", "video" )
GROUP BY ID

SELECT ID, post_title, post_content,
MAX( CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = "thumnail" THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value ELSE '' END ) AS Thumbnail,
MAX( CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = "video" THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value ELSE '' END ) AS Video
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id=wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key IN( "thumnail", "video" )
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, after reading up on IF Statements I cant figure out the logic of what you're doing with MAX, works but want do understand why??

Comment: Aggregate function is used when grouping, without GROUP BY output will have duplicate rows, and without MAX ( SUM or COUNT can be used also ) it will have empty values. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns/9668036#9668036) answer for better explanation.

Comment: Aha, makes sense - thanks. Whilst here, could you offer advice on how to add the post categories to this - I have used the same logic in your answer but come unstuck as there is no unique value (ie as in meta_key), they are all just 'category'. I can output the first, but not all...

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask a new question, so that others can participate also, and to get a better view of the problem. By the way, if this answer helped then maybe you should mark the answers as Accepted.